# how to rise 404 in django-annoying

Tags: django

How to rise 404 error, when I use `django-annoying`'s `@render_to`?

e.g.:

```
@render_to('page.html')
def v_page(request, page_id):
    page = get_object_or_None(Page, id=page_id)
    if page:
         return {'page': page}
    # raise 404 here
```

I read `django-annoying` documentation and didn't find an answer. I guess the answer should be very obvious, but it is not obvious for me.

Comment: I can't see any reason to still use `render_to`, since Django has provided the [`render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut since version 1.3.

Comment: Daniel Roseman, with `@render_to` you don't have to write `request` as first argument everytime (like in `render()`). Also template name is on the top of view function, I find it more convinient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[See here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception), and [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-get-object-or-404) is better suited in this case.

```
from django.http import Http404

@render_to('page.html')
def v_page(request, page_id):
    page = get_object_or_None(Page, id=page_id)
    if page:
         return {'page': page}

    # raise 404 here
    raise Http404
```

Comment: I tried `get_object_or_404`, but it does not work with `@render_to`

Comment: @daniel-roseman is right, you should take a look at **[render()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)** and **[render_to_response()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response)**